# angular pouchdb -ERROR Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable

Tags: angular, pouchdb

I'm trying to install PouchDB inside an Angular application. This has worked for me in the past but now when I try to create a new project I get the error: 
`" Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable "`

I'm not sure why this is the bug that I am getting, does this have something to do with the new Angular? Or maybe PouchDB version 6.3? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved it by using a lower node.js version:

```
$ nvm list

  * 8.3.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    7.4.0
    6.10.0
    4.4.7
    4.3.0

$ nvm use 7.4.0
$ npm i --save pouchdb
...
$ nvm use 8.3.0
```

The reason is that leveldown, which is used by pouchdb has pre-packaged binaries that correspond to your OS and node versions, since it could not find mine, it tried to build it but for some reason (maybe Windows backslash issue) it could not.

Comment: Your solution worked. Now I'm getting the error: `ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_pouchdb__ is not a constructor` I'm pretty sure this is something specific to my pre-existing code

Comment: Great! Yes, I'm sorry but I don't know about this other error.

Comment: Yeah it's odd, the error is pointing to this line in my code `this.db = new PouchDB('users');`, which is inside my constructor